# A prime ring with characteristic different from 2 is 2-torsion free.

Tags: ring-theory

I know that a prime ring R is a ring in which the zero ideal is a prime ideal, i.e., aRb=0 implies either a=0 or b=0.
To prove R is 2-torsion free I want to prove that there is no nonzero x in R such that 2x=0.
My approach: Suppose there exists a nonzero x in R such that 2x=0. I seek a contradiction but I am not able to find it.

Please someone suggest to me how I should approach this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $x\ne0$ but $2x=0$. For every $y\in R$, we have $xR(2y)=(2x)Ry=0$. Since $R$ is prime, it follows that either $x=0$ (which is false by assumption) or $2y=0$. Thus, $2y=0$ for every $y\in R$; i.e., $R$ has characteristic $2$.